Does G-computation have any advantages over propensity score based methods for very small sample sizes (e.g., <40)
I am looking into the use of g-computation methods as an alternative for causal inference analysis to propensity score based methods (e.g., IPTW, matching). Does anyone have any examples of using this method in very small sample sizes/literature that demonstrates its benefit. Thanks.

You probably need to provide some more detail about your setting - g-computation is typically useful in settings where you have either longitudinal treatments (i.e. a treat at time 1, treat at time 2, etc.) or mediation. Matching in particular is not really applicable in those settings, so it's hard to give an answer without knowing more.

Thanks - its a static exposure setting (treated vs non treated) comparing intervention to a SOC - we are focusing on IPTW to balance the cohorts to estimate outcomes such as OS, PFS etc, however for some indications we have very small estimated cohort sizes (e.g., <40) and the question is more about whether g-computation would provide any advanatge in this setting vs IPTW

@MartinQLD G-computation is perfectly valid for point treatments. In fact, it is much harder to do g-computation for longitudinal treatments because you have to model ever time-varying confounder and using simulation to estimate the treatment effects. For point treatments, it is equivalent to well-known and simple methods like average marginal effects.

@Noah - yes, the equivalence to standard methods is exactly why I would think g-computation is typically unnecessary for point treatments. Is there another reason why I would use g-computation when there are faster/simpler/more widely understood alternatives for point treatments?

@MartinQLD I'm not sure what other alternatives you are thinking of. Regressing the outcome on treatment and confounders is g-computation (in its simplest form). If you use a nonlinear link function (e.g., logit) then the only way to get a marginal treatment effect estimate is by computing the model-implied potential outcome estimates under each treatment, which is g-computation.

@Noah thanks for getting back to me - perhaps there is some mixed terminology here - I (and others I know) would routinely calculate marginal effects after logistic regression without ever thinking of this as g-computation. Given that the original motivation for the development of the g-formula was specifically to deal with time-varying confounding, and introductions to the topic are also usually couched in those terms (e.g. Naimi 2017 in IJE) my impression was that g-computation referred specifically to simulating from the model. Is that incorrect?

@MartinQLD the method is introduced in Ch 13 of  Hernán and Robins (2020) textbook for single time point treatments. It is described in Snowden et al. (2011) for single time point treatments. It is very complicated to use for longitudinal treatments, so I would argue it is more common for point treatments, whereas IPW is more popular for longitudinal treatments.

Mechanically, it is identical to AMEs but it is designed to estimate a specific causal effects, whereas AMEs are routinely used to summarize the results of an entire logistic regression model. G-computation goes by many names, including regression estimation, regression imputation, g-formula, etc. It is implemented in Stata teffects ra and SAS PROC CAUSALTRT.
